# How to call method on previous page?

Tags: windows-phone-7

is there any way to call method or set propery of the previous page in the stack?
Say I started a thread in the A page, then navigated to page B, now my application is going to be deactivated and I want to take care of the thread started in the page A, I want to call a method of A that will save thread job's some parameters. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a method on a previous page.

You should be deactivating the thread when you leave page A. If that doesn't work for your application, then the thread is an application-level feature and should be created/deactivated in Application class.

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful, what about to use BackgroundWorkers to bind thread's cancelation job with the main job?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by jobs

Comment: I solved my problem by putting my BackgroundWorker objects in the application-level container and simply called their CloseAsync methods on application deactivated event handler delegate. Each bckWorker has a work to do before dying(e.g. save something in the storage) and the bckWorker do that work itself, I've abstracted the App-level from that work, that was my goal. Thanks.